# Convert WRF UTC time to Local time

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have to make spatial plots from a bunch of WRFout files that I have. Currently, I am using following lines of code to print the respective times for each spatial plot

```
#..Load packages
import os
import netCDF4
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap,addcyclic,cm,shiftgrid
from wrf import getvar,get_basemap,to_np,latlon_coords

#..Read the files
fpath = sorted(glob.glob("/path/wrfout_d01_2017-03-02_00:00:00"))
with netCDF4.Dataset(fpath, 'r') as fin:

#..Read variables
p  = getvar(fin,'pressure')
times = getvar(fin,'times',meta=False)

#..Make the pressure plot
fig = plt.figure()
mp = get_basemap(p)
x,y = mp(to_np(lons),to_np(lats))
cntrs = mp.contourf(x,y,p,cmap='jet')
plt.title(str(to_np(times))[0:-10])
plt.show()
```

The `times` variable gives time in the format `2017-03-02T00:00:00.000000000`.

The line of code `plt.title(str(to_np(times))[0:-10])` prints the time as `2017-03-02T00:00:00`, which is a UTC time. But, I want it to be printed as `2017-03-01 17:00:00`, which is the local time `(UTC- 7 hours)`.

Thanks in advance, any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas to do the conversion.You can choose the timezone that works for you.
Just added the snippet thats useful.

```
import pandas as pd

#..Read variables
...
times = getvar(fin,'times',meta=False)
mountainTime = pd.Timestamp(times,tz='US/Mountain')

#..Make the pressure plot
...
plt.title(str(mountainTime)[0:-6])
```

Comment: Using pandas actually helped. Thanks and it was very easy.

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```
import datetime

dt=datetime.datetime.strptime("2017-03-02T00:00:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S") #Get your datetime object
dt=dt.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc) #Convert it to an aware datetime object in UTC time.
print(dt) #You do not need this line. For show only :P
dt=dt.astimezone() #Convert it to your local timezone
print(dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

Output:

```
2017-03-02 00:00:00+00:00
2017-03-02 05:30:00
```

Now my timezone is UTC+5:30 (India). So, showing that. Yours should give your.